# HTML/jQuery - Make TextArea Behaviour like Command Line

Tags: jquery, html, text, command-line, position

I am trying to make a textarea look and behave like a command line, but I have one problem now..

Each time the user writes a command and presses 'Enter', I don't want the user to be able to write on lines above, but he can copy the content written before.

So the challenge is, how to limitate the lines where user can write?

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: what if you use one text input and store previous lines in a div?

Comment: because that won't look like a command line..

Comment: You can use CSS (On input and DIv) to make it look like a command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if we disable going back up?

Like:

HTML

```
<textarea id="command-line"></textarea>
```

Jquery

```
$('#command-line').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 38){
        return false;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RE9hk/4/

EDIT: flaw is the mouse which can be used to set the cursor, or have turned that off (in cmd (windows) it's not possible to use the mouse)

Comment: Yes in cmd it's not possible to use the mouse to type text but its possible to use mouse to copy text on the cmd..

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is an older post, but in case anyone else stumbles on it looking for similar solutions, maybe take a look at the JQuery Terminal Emulator: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

The JQuery Terminal Emulator is essentially a Javascript-based plugin for creating command line interpreters in web applications. It can be configured to interact locally (i.e. through Javascript logic in the browser) or it can bet setup to automatically call an JSON-RPC service.  It includes support for several other features that are familiar for a terminal, such as tab-completion and command history. It also looks pretty cool.  :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  An answer that is mostly just a link should have at least some substance of the link.  At least you give a search term the OP can look up if the link breaks, but if the link does break, this will be a mostly useless answer.  Consider expanding on it to make this a high quality answer.  Thanks!